# CIDR range Azure vNet

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Hi I'm trying to deploy a virtual network in Azure and I'm getting this strange error. I've checked the CIDR notation online and it seems valid. 172.19.20.0/22, we've managed to use 172.19.16.0/22 and the next one we're deploying is failing.

```
The address prefix 172.19.20/22 in resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/rg-network-01/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET2-UKS-01 has an invalid CIDR notation. For the given prefix length, the address prefix should be 172.19.0.0/22." Details=[]
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm not great with networking :(

Comment: are you creating the vnet from portal, arn / cli ? could you paste your script please.

Comment: Hi I’m creating from terraform and from portal and fails both times.

Comment: @Thomas I should have mentioned I’ve created the 172.19.16.0/22 with the same code and also 172.19.12.0/22, but the third one fails, which is 172.19.20.0/22

Comment: I've just tried from azure portal and it is working fine. are you sure the subnets have also the right address space ?

Comment: @Thomas I can create it in my msdn subscription which is why I’m so confused, the address space is 172.19.0.0/16

Comment: So your vnet is `172.19.16.0/22` and the subnet is `172.19.0.0/16` or the other way around ?

Comment: @Thomas sorry what I mean is 172.19.0.0/16 is the address space in azure and out vnet is 172.12.0/22 and 172.19.16.0/22 .. when we try to create a new vnet 172.19.20.0/22 it fails, which is bizarre

Comment: there has to be a typo somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding from your question and comments, you have a Vnet address space of 172.19.0.0/16 and you want to create subnet with address space 172.19.12.0/22, 172.19.16.0/22 and 172.19.20.0/22. You are facing issue while creating 172.19.20.0/22 subnet space with error

> The address prefix 172.19.20/22 in resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/rg-network-01/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET2-UKS-01 has an invalid CIDR notation. For the given prefix length, the address prefix should be 172.19.0.0/22." Details=[]

I think the issue here is due to a wrong subnet address provided in the command 172.19.20/22 it should be 172.19.20.0/22 instead. I get a similar error if try it on my end.

[image]